# Java Scanner multiple delimiter

Tags: java

I know this is a very asked question but I can't find and apropiate answer for my problem. Thing is I have to program and aplication that reads from a .TXT file like this

```
Real:Atelti
Alcorcon:getafe 
Barcelona:Sporting
```

My question is how what can I do to tell Java that I want String before : in one ArrayList and Strings after : in another ArrayList?? I guess It's using delimeter method but I don't know how use it in this case.

Sorry for my poor english, I've to improve It i guess. Thanks

Comment: gave you a complete, working example. please try it.

Answer (score 1):

use split function of java.

steps:

1. Declare two arrayList. l1 and l2;
2. read each line.
3. split each line by ":", this will return a array of length 2, array. (as per your input)
4. l1.add(array[0]) , l2.add(array[1](http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example))

try yourself, post code if you need help :)

check [here](http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example) for use of split function, though through google you can find many different example

Comment: ok, before code it just one question, When you say "split each line by ":" " you mean using delimitator or some method from String?

Comment: ok, I see what you mean, but I'm force to do it using delimeter method (all this is because a School test) and I can't use the split stuff. I guess I have to combine both delimeters ":" and "\n" but still don't know how.

Comment: friend look at post given by @Buffalo. nextLine() method gives the complete line. and you can iterate line by line using this method, you need not to split defferent-lines on your own. You just need to split using ':'

Answer (score 1):

Split the string using ":" as delimiter. Add the odd entries from the result to one list and even to another list.

Answer (score 1):

If your text is like this:

Real:Atelti

Alcorcon:getafe

Barcelona:Sporting

You can achieve what you want by using:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fFileName), encoding); //try utf8 or utf-8 for 'encoding'
try {
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String before = line.split(":")[0];
    String after = line.split(":")[1];
    //dsw 'before' and 'after' - add them to lists.
  }
}
finally{
  scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("YOUR_FILE_PATH"));
        List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> secondList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] tokenizedString = currentLine.split(":");
            firstList.add(tokenizedString[0]);
            secondList.add(tokenizedString[1]);
        }
              scanner.close();
```

Enumerating firstList and secondList will get you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use `":"` as delimiter.

**2.** Then Store them in the `String[]` using `split()` function.

**3.** Try using `BufferedReader` instead of Scanner.

**Eg:**

```
File f = new File("d:\\Mytext.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
ArrayList<String> s1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> s2 = new ArrayList<String>();

  while ((br.readLine())!=null){

    String line = br.readLine();

    String bf = line.split(":")[0];
    String af = line.split(":")[1];

    s1.add(bf);
    s2.add(af);

  }
```